# How can I add a zip folder to an asset field in craft cms

Tags: craft3, craft4

I'm quite new to the cms and would like to know how to programmatically add a zip folder to an asset field in craft cms using a plugin. So like listening to ENTRY_AFTER_EVENT and processing a zip folder and afterwards do something like `$event->sender->assetField = zippedFolder`

Any assistance is highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Zipped folder? Do you mean folder with zip files or what? Do you need to reattach (change) an asset for certain fields?

Comment: While I agree the question could be more precise, you could consider to build on top of an existing plugin like https://plugins.craftcms.com/compress?craft4.

Comment: @RomanAvr I meant a compressed folder with some files in it.

Comment: @IronBrew It's a bit difficult to understand what you're asking. Please clarify further what you're trying to do, in as much detail as possible :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for assistance.
I was able to solve the problem by creating an asset, got the asset id and added the asset field to the id:
$event->sender->assetField = [newassetid];